# How to save cookie acceptance in a log file log?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is it posible to log the cookie acceptance, meaning each time when a user accept cookies to have that recorded in a log file stored on the server, in case we need to prove later that he accepted the cookies?
Is there any documentation on how to build that with javascrip?
On my serch results i get only nonsense :((

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

After they accept cookies, you could store the state locally (with a cookie or localStorage).

If you need to save in server-side, you could set up a backend API. For example:

`api.example.com/save-accept-cookie` stores the state of a cookie in a database, using the clients IP

Client-side, you could make a post request to the API endpoint

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm already doing that locally with cookie. But I wanted to save the acceptance for about an year, in case the user delete the local storage and I need to prove the consent. Your third suggestion I think it's most feasable for my purposes. Thank you

Comment: Then you would use a backend API